# Oracle Weblogic \MySQL \MySQL unexpected at this time

Tags: java, mysql, maven, weblogic-10.x

I am trying to run an application cloned from a git repo on my local system. After cloning and maven install, when I try to start the oracle web logic server, I get the error:

**\MySQL \MySQL unexpected at this time**

I tried removing MySQL from classpath and path of environment variables and even uninstalled MySQL Connector J thinking that MySQL was creating these problems but no matter what I do, it always keeps giving this error and the server doesn't start at all.

These are the steps that I have followed: 
1. Cloned the repo. 
2. Imported all the files to eclipse. 
3. Created a new weblogic server on eclipse.
4. Did maven clean and install: build is successful. 
5. Try to run the server to get the above mentioned error.

I'm a newbie to Oracle WebLogic server and I'm using the version 10.3.5

Any help will be very much helpful.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in the application.  Or maybe there are installation or configuration instructions for the application that you didn't read or follow correctly.  Hint: if you want us to helpful, you need to provide more information.

Comment: The application works on other systems. I'm new to Maven Apache and Oracle Web Logic. I'm also running a java application which makes use of MySQL. Is that creating any issues?

Answer (score 3):

Various MySQL installs push an entry into your PATH environment variable like:

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Enterprise Backup 3.11\;"C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.3 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.3 1.5\";C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;

Yours could be different depending upon which MySQL components you installed.
The exact sequence of spaces and quotes can be a problem when the "set" command is called to start a window.  If you don't need the MySQL binaries in your PATH you could pull all of that out.  If you do need it, they experiment with the location of quotes and even installation directories so that the problem goes away.

Comment: I have a batch file which calls the VS tools so I see:      Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x86 tools.
\MySQL\MySQL was unexpected at this time.    >        set "PATH=C:\Program Files\...."   So the SET process encloses the PATH in quotes.  Quotes in the path therefore are a problem

Comment: I have this same issue with running vsdevcmd.bat